# References between two included files?

Tags: cross-referencing

I am using TeXMaker, and I am trying to cross reference between two included files, but it does not seem to work.

Let me explain better: I have a file A, which `\include{file_B}` and `\include{file_C}`.

Now in `file_B` I want to put a reference to a section of `file_C`, but in `file_B` the `\ref` recognizes only the sections of `file_B`, it does not recognize those of `file_C`.

Note that `file_B` and `file_C` are conceived to be chapters of a same thesis, and do not have a preamble.

Note also that in `file_A` the `\ref` does recognize all the sections of both `file_B` and `file_C`. But this works only in `file_A`.

Is there a way to do so?
Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you get the references in the PDF file (compile twice) and are you only missing some kind of checking / auto competition in you editor? Normally TeX gets references between different file without problems. (They are saved in `*.aux` files).

Comment: The `\include` system is designed to support cross-references if the files are included in the same master document. If there are cross-references to other master documents, use the `xr` package

Comment: Please, add a minimal example showing the issue. Are you perhaps doing `\include{A}` and in `A.tex` you have `\include{B}` and `\include{C}`?